# Python zipfile write file before 1980

Tags: linux, python-3.x, zip

I am trying to create a zip file with Python 3.5.2 [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html), on Linux. Some of the files I'm trying to add have timestamps of 1-Jan-1970 (embedded system without a real-time clock module). So `zipfile` gives an exception:

```
ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980
```

My goal then is to implement a work-around to add these files to the zip file with a timestamp of 1-Jan-1980. However, I am finding it difficult to find a suitable work-around.

At first I thought I can do this:

```
def zinfo_from_file(fullname, arcname):
    st = os.stat(fullname)
    mtime = time.localtime(st.st_mtime)
    date_time = mtime[0:6]
    if date_time[0] < 1980:
        date_time = (1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    zinfo = zipfile.ZipInfo(arcname, date_time)
    return zinfo

...
zinfo = zinfo_from_file(fullname, arcname)
chunksize=512
with open(fullname, 'rb') as src, myzipfile.open(zinfo, 'w') as dest:
    while True:
        data = src.read(chunksize)
        if not data:
            break
        dest.write(data)
...
```

However, it turns out that `myzipfile.open(zinfo, 'w')` is [not supported until Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open). (I'm using Yocto to build embedded Linux, which currently only supports Python 3.5.x.)

I guess I could try doing `myzipfile.writestr(zinfo, ...)`, although then it appears that I have to load the entire file data into memory.

Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: Why not just change the timestamp on the file?

Comment: @l'L'l that requires giving the Python program permissions that I'd rather it doesn't have.

Comment: One option I'll consider though is to have a system initscript that sets the system time to >= 1980, and then updates the timestamp on the files that I care about.

Comment: Another way is to possibly substitute in the timestamp from another source (like a controller) instead of from the machine without the real clock. Is this a raspberry PI or something similar?

Comment: @l'L'l It's a BeagleBone Black. I'm not quite understanding your suggestion.

Comment: With raspberry PI there is a way to use a controller to manipulate the time, but you aren't so forget that idea. I vaguely remember a way for changing the timestamp specifically for `zipfile.write()`  ( similar to how `zipfile.writestr()` uses `zipfile.ZipInfo()` ), although in a more convoluted way. If you're interested I can find the code responsible and maybe that would be a possible solution...

Answer (score 0):

checked your file's modify time . If your file hasn't modify time ,you can write a line or enter in it. And Zip this file or directory again.

Comment: `os.utime ()` might be handy. If he has the right to modify the file or copy it elsewhere

Comment: yeah，it seems to easier。